# How to use different font types in XSL-FO?

Tags: xsl-fo

I am making a PDF file using XSL-FO. For the styling purpose I wish to use different Font types like (Arial, Algerian, Copper Black etc) which are present in MS Word. How many font types are supported in XSL-FO and which attribute can I use to achieve this.

I have tried "font-style" and "font-family", but seems like they don't support many as I have read from the doc.

Answer (score 1):

Your XSL Formatter can use any font that it knows about. `font-family="Arial"`, for example, will work if the XSL Formatter knows about Arial.

The details for how to configure your XSL Formatter to find the fonts on your system varies with the formatter.  AH Formatter has a font configuration file (see https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf66/ahf-font.html#font-configration-file), although, on Windows, the formatter includes all of the fonts in the Windows font directory by default.  FOP has its own configuration mechanism (see https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/configuration.html#general-elements), as do other formatters.